# Microsoft Dynamics 4.0 SDK Check If User Has Privilege

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

We were previously using an unsupported dll (`Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Core`) to check if the current user in Dynamics has read privileges on a specific entity:

```
Microsoft.Crm.Security.User.HasPrivilege(Microsoft.Crm.Security.User.Current,   
 "myentityname, AccessRights.ReadAccess);
```

I need to do the same thing using only the supported SDK (and the CrmService).

Can someone advise on how to accomplish this using the SDK?

Comment: I have found way how to accomplish this using bare SDK: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16042098/1047741

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably design a Fetch or QueryExpression like so:

1. Retrieve on the entity privilege
2. Join on entity roleprivilege where privilege.privilegeid = roleprivilege.privilegeid
3. Join on entity systemuserrole where systemuserrole.roleid = roleprivileges.roleid and systemuserrole.systemuserid = (GUID of the user in question)
4. Then either iterate through the privileges or look for privilege where privilege.name =  "prvReadMyEntityName"

Just be careful on the results, because you may get different privilege depths from different roles, but if you don't care about the depth then I think that'll do it.

Comment: Thanks...I have no idea how to do this though. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" count="1000" version="1.0">
    <entity name="privilege">
        <attribute name="name" />
        <filter>
            <condition attribute="name" operator="eq" value="prvCreateINSERTYOURENTITYHERE" />
        </filter>
        <link-entity name="roleprivileges" from="privilegeid" to="privilegeid">
            <link-entity name="role" from="roleid" to="roleid">
                <link-entity name="systemuserroles" from="roleid" to="roleid">
                    <link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="systemuserid">
                        <filter>
                            <condition attribute="fullname" operator="eq" value="INSERT NAME HERE" />
                        </filter>
                    </link-entity>
                </link-entity>
            </link-entity>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Searching by FullName is not good idea, it's better to use GUID instead.

Comment: ...but otherwise a neat, quick solution. Thanks Alberto.