# How to get current user privileges in MS Dynamics CRM on server side

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm working on MS CRM plugin, and it should be able to determine whether the current user has write access to the current entity. I don't know how to approach this task.

It seems that the most user-friendly way accomplish this task is currently [unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5147974/1047741).

Is there any alternative in MS CRM 2011 SDK, except composing a FetchXML query and parsing its output?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is what I have come up with — this code will check, does current user has given privilege on current record:

```
// Requesting user's access rights to current record
var principalAccessRequest = new RetrievePrincipalAccessRequest
{
    Principal = new EntityReference("systemuser", localContext.PluginExecutionContext.UserId),
    Target = new EntityReference(localContext.PluginExecutionContext.PrimaryEntityName, localContext.PluginExecutionContext.PrimaryEntityId)
};

// Response will contain AccessRights mask, like AccessRights.WriteAccess | AccessRights.ReadAccess | ...
var principalAccessResponse = (RetrievePrincipalAccessResponse)localContext.OrganizationService.Execute(principalAccessRequest);

if ((principalAccessResponse.AccessRights & AccessRights.WriteAccess) != AccessRights.None)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

The code inside `if` statement will be executed if user has `WriteAccess` to current record.

Answer (score 1):

According to Matt's Answer:

1. Retrieve on the entity privilege
2. Join on entity roleprivilege where privilege.privilegeid = roleprivilege.privilegeid
3. Join on entity systemuserrole where systemuserrole.roleid = roleprivileges.roleid and systemuserrole.systemuserid = (GUID of the user in question)
4. Then either iterate through the privileges or look for privilege where privilege.name =  "prvReadMyEntityName"

You have just have to perform the joins and add the where clause you care about.  Here is the Equivalent SQL:

```sql
SELECT Privilege.*
FROM Privilege
INNER JOIN RolePrivilege ON Privilege.PrivilegeId = RolePrivilege.PrivilegeId
INNER JOIN SystemUserRole ON SystemUserRole.RoleId = RolePrivileges.RoleId AND SystemUserRole.SystemUserId = (user's GUID)
-- WHERE Add whatever constraints on the Privilege entity that you need
```

You can perform this using Fetch XML, or LINQ to CRM, or Query Expressions, or even OData.