# How to query privileges specific to entity (without the ID of the entity record) using CRM 2011/2013 sdk?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

Creating an external MVC website using CRM 2011/2013 web services. Must hide/show parts of the application based on write access to a certain custom entity. Found solutions like

http://mileyja.blogspot.de/2011/05/using-retrieveuserprivileges-requests.html

Here the RetrieveUserPrivilegesRequest requires the systemuser id and the entity record id as parameters. Workarounds on the subject use .First() to get a record and retrieve the privileges. The solution is not convincing because of the possibility of the absence of records.

The other solutions as RetrieveUserPrivilegesRequest returns Guid-s of privileges. These can change from CRM instance to instance. Also roles get things complicated. Does anyone knowif there exists a straight forward way to 
verify if the system user has write access to a certain entity?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038346/how-to-get-current-user-privileges-in-ms-dynamics-crm-on-server-side

Comment: Thanks, but I have been through the link. It doesn't really help. As mentioned it returns Guid-s and these change system to system. I am searching for a more generic way.

Comment: The set of privileges a user has is cached on the web server and you should be able to get at that with a single message without then needing to go query anything else to match them up. This caching is why you should use privileges to test for a user's access, rather than membership of security roles (not cached), so your approach is the right one. Note that the result set should give the 'deepest' privilege the user has as a sum of all roles on the user and their teams. This is sufficient for checking for yor purposes. Unfortunately I don't know the right bits of code you need to use.

Comment: Received an answer from the CRM dynamics community website by Scott  Durow and Guido Preite. Here is the link to the conversation: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/141175/307247.aspx#307247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requirement can be fulfilled by a combination of a `QueryExpression` and a `RetrieveUserPrivilegesRequest` or by a single `QueryExpression`.

[Check if a User has a specific Privilege](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/09/check-if-user-has-specific-privilege.html)